# Calling Access 2013 Module from C# Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, automation, ms-access-2013

I've started dabbling in automation of MS Office products from win forms and have hit a wall. As the title suggests, I'm using C# in VS2010 (.NET 4.0), connected to an Access 2013 back end.

Here's my issue, I'm trying to run a module in my program's back end database. I've seen a number of posts here on Stack and read a few articles on MSDN and have come up with the following:

```
using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
void RunAccessModule() 
{
    try
    {
        Access.Application oAccess = new Access.Application();
        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("H:\\MyConnection\\UtilityBackEnd.accdb", false);
        oAccess.Run("MakeProjectTable"); //Name of procedure in module
        oAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.Message;
    }
}
```

When I run my program I get an error that reads: `"Microsoft Access cannot find the procedure 'MakeProjectTable.'"` I've tried being more specific with the run command (i.e.`oAccess.Run("Module1.MakeProjectTable");` ), but I received a similar error message (`cannot find 'Module1.MakeProjectTable.'`. Can anyone see an issue with what I have so far, and/or suggest a ?

Comment: As documented, the Run() method can only invoke VBA code.  Use DoCmd instead.

Comment: Is `MakeProjectTable` a `Public` procedure in a standard module in your `UtilityBackEnd.accdb` database?

Comment: No, i'll change it now

Comment: The error occurred after the change.

Comment: For clarification, the declaration line now reads: `Public Sub MakeProjectTable()`

Comment: @HansPassant what child function of DoCmd should I be looking to use?

Comment: Have you tried RunMacro?  Looked like that is what you were trying to do.

Comment: I was under the impression that modules and macros were 2 different objects. Can the RunMacro command run a module?

Comment: @HansUp would including the Access module's methods in my post suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# code will work if you have declared your VBA (Access) code as

```vbs
Public Sub MakeProjectTable()
```

in a "regular" `Module`, not a `Class Module` or a `Microsoft Access Class Object`. In other words, if you open the database in Access and look at the `Sub` in the VBA editor it must be located in a module under the "Modules" folder of the Project Explorer:

[image: Module.png]

Comment: This seems correct; it's what I tried to tell them 2 days ago.  :-)  If they still have trouble, open `H:\MyConnection\UtilityBackEnd.accdb` in a standalone Access session and make sure this actually works: `Application.Run "MakeProjectTable"`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I thought maybe a pretty picture might help. :)

Comment: I think it should!  It occurs to me just saying *standard* module was not sufficient.  :-(

Comment: @HansUp I'm really sorry for not understanding you earlier, I just tried this and it worked first shot, thank you both.